# Read shapefile of points and store node ids as input to a function?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, geopandas, shapefile

I'm trying to run a function called pcst_fast using a shapefile of points. It takes in an edge list of the form [[startnode_id, endnode_id]...], a costs lists (which is just the length of each road segment), and a prizes list. The prizes list is 0 everywhere and 9999 where the node id corresponds to a point in the input shapefile.

How do I pass in the coordinates in the input points alapts.shp as ids into this function? I need to somehow create node ids everywhere a road segment starts, ends, or there is an input point.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import geopandas as gpd
import momepy
import pcst_fast
from pyproj import CRS
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely import wkt
from shapely.ops import nearest_points, split
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString
import rtree

roads = gpd.read_file("alaroads.shp")
pts = gpd.read_file("alapts.shp")

roads['length'] = roads.geometry.length
lens = list(roads.length.copy())
roads.crs = "EPSG:4326"
roads = roads.to_crs(crs='EPSG:4326')
roads['source_coords'] = roads.geometry.apply(lambda x: Point(x.coords[0]))
roads['target_coords'] = roads.geometry.apply(lambda x: Point(x.coords[-1]))

edge_list = ????
costs = list(roads.length)
prizes = ??????  # some of these need to have value 9999, the ones that correspond to points in alapts.shp

# run the function
pcst_fast.pcst_fast(edge_list, prizes, costs, -1, 1, "gw", 1)
```